# How to use jquery function result as parameter in html.actionlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have simple `@html.actionlink("action", "controller", new {id = somevalue})`

and jquery function

```
<script>
    function getValue() {
        var p = $("#EditId").val();
        return p;
    }
</script>
```

How to use return value of this function instead of "`somevalue`" in actionlink?

Comment: in `@html.actionlink("action", "controller", new {id = somevalue})` you use server side code, `getValue` is client side code, so this are two independent part

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
@html.actionlink("action", "controller", new {id = somevalue,@class="link"})

<script>
function getValue() {
    var p = $("#EditId").val();

    return p;
}
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(".link").attr('id')=getValue();
  });
   </script>
```

Or:

```
 $(".link").href.replace("somevalue", getValue());
```

Comment: this will be the alternate i think

Comment: You should remove  `$(".link").attr('id')=getValue();` as third parameter is route values see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936(v=vs.118).aspx. And use `$(".link").href.replace("somevalue", getValue());`

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is impossible as you describe it because the @Html.ActionLink is a server side code and renders **a tag** when JS involved the @Html.ActionLink finished its job and gone.

Also as you are trying change the id of element this might be also impossible for later access (not sure).

As a work around you can ad the link with JS function with a place-holder. Try below and tell me is it is working

instead of @Html.ActionLink use the below;

```
<div id="linkPlaceHolder"></div>
```

on load use the following

```
$(function(){
 var actionUrl = @Url.Action("action", controller); // you get the url of action

 $("#linkPlaceHolder").replaceWith("<a href='"+actionUrl+"' id='" + getValue() + "'>Text</a>")
});
```

this should work and if not or not exactly what you want we are here.

Comment: Thanks for response, i'll try it... Just to clarify, i'm not trying to change id of an element, id here is parameter that is passed to controller action.